# Apache httpd whitelist access control via X-Forwarded-For header

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I have the following httpd.conf file which I am using to test `X-Forwarded-For` header IP whitelisting.  Note that the `conf.d` directory is empty:

```
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Listen 443

User dev
Group dev
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName my-httpd-server

<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Files ".ht*">
Require all denied
</Files>

<IfModule mime_module>
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>


AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    LogLevel debug
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    #Satisfy any


    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^171.159.192.10 letmein

    Allow from env=letmein

     Satisfy any
</Directory>


IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

When I cURL to get the local page with this server, it works regardless of the XFF header:

`curl -H 'X-Forwarded-For: 8.8.8.8' http://localhost`

`curl http://localhost`

These work, but print the following in the error log (These requests should *not work*):

```
[Mon Dec 17 10:24:53.346021 2018] [access_compat:error] [pid 12] [client 172.17.0.1:49010] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Mon Dec 17 10:24:53.346614 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.17.0.1:49010] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Dec 17 10:24:53.347603 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.17.0.1:49010] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
```

The following request from the whitelisted IP works but without the logging noise:

`curl -H 'X-Forwarded-For: 171.159.192.10' http://localhost:8181/`

What is causing the requests that should fail to return the web page?  I get the message that it should be denied based on the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the `satisfy any` bit to be changed to `satisfy all`. That refers to allowing a user if they meet the authentication OR access requirements. Since I don't see an authtype set, it's defaulted to `AuthType none` which I think allows them to pass in.  `satisfy all` means Authentication AND Access are required to be met.